# Rearrange list by drag and drop in Android

Tags: android, listview

How can I create a list where I can rearrange list items with dragging list rows to another row and so on (to change to order)?

I saw some reference link (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/master/src/com/android/music/TouchInterceptor.java) in some previous posts. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this link](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html)

And by default project code will compile in JDK 1.4.

So change it from 1.4 to 1.5